# Drawing a circle of smallest radius around a quadrilateral using R

Tags: r

Let us consider a quadrilateral with vertices

```
       x            y
1   0.0057      -0.0249
2   0.0209       0.0028
3  -0.0058       0.0250
4  -0.0209      -0.0028.
```

Could anyone please suggest me if there is any package or code in R to find and draw circle of smallest radius around the above quadrilateral. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know about any library that can solve your problem from start but one way of doing it could be

- Determine minimum radius (depending on what kind of  cuadrilateral you have ie. square or rectangle)
- Use this `draw.circle` from `plotrix` library as explained [here](http://www.inside-r.org/packages/cran/plotrix/docs/draw.circle)

**UPDATE**
In this particular example the quadrilateral looks like this:
[image]

using

```
ggplot(rectangle,aes(x=x,y=y)) + geom_polygon(aes(x=x,y=y), colour="black", fill = NA)
```

where rectangle is

```
rectangle = data.frame("x"=c(0.0057,0.0209,-0.0058,-0.0209),"y"=c(-0.029,0.028,0.0250,-0.0028))
```

So you would have to calculate the center of the polygon:

1. Get the equation for diagonal one
2. Get the equation for diagonal two
3. Get the intersection of the lines (solve equation1 = equation 2) which is the center of the shape
4. Calculate the distances of the center to each side and use the minimum distance as the minimum radius.
5. Draw the circle with the previous radius calculated.

Should be easy to do all the calculations for this particular example.

Comment: I think I can use the centroid to plot the circle using draw.circle function. It is working fine. Thanks for your suggestion.

Comment: Glad I could help, show me some love and give it a tick ;)

Answer (score 0):

i hope this will help you. goodluck

```
pack.circles <- function(config, size=c(100, 100), max.iter=1000, overlap=0) {
#
# Simple circle packing algorithm based on inverse size weighted repulsion
#
# config   - matrix with two cols: radius, N
# size     - width and height of bounding rectangle
# max.iter - maximum number of iterations to try
# overlap  - allowable overlap expressed as proportion of joint radii

# ============================================================================
#  Global constants
# ============================================================================
# round-off tolerance
TOL <- 0.0001

# convert overlap to proportion of radius
if (overlap < 0 | overlap >= 1) {
  stop("overlap should be in the range [0, 1)")
}
PRADIUS <- 1 - overlap

NCIRCLES <- sum(config[,2])

# ============================================================================
#  Helper function - Draw a circle
# ============================================================================
draw.circle <- function(x, y, r, col) { 
  lines( cos(seq(0, 2*pi, pi/180)) * r + x, sin(seq(0, 2*pi, pi/180)) * r + y , col=col )
}


# ============================================================================
#  Helper function - Move two circles apart. The proportion of the required
#  distance moved by each circle is proportional to the size of the other 
#  circle. For example, If a c1 with radius r1 overlaps c2 with radius r2,
#  and the movement distance required to separate them is ds, then c1 will
#  move ds * r2 / (r1 + r2) while c2 will move ds * r1 / (r1 + r2). Thus,
#  when a big circle overlaps a little one, the little one moves a lot while
#  the big one moves a little.
# ============================================================================
repel <- function(xyr, c0, c1) {
  dx <- xyr[c1, 1] - xyr[c0, 1]
  dy <- xyr[c1, 2] - xyr[c0, 2]
  d <- sqrt(dx*dx + dy*dy)
  r <- xyr[c1, 3] + xyr[c0, 3]
  w0 <- xyr[c1, 3] / r
  w1 <- xyr[c0, 3] / r

if (d < r - TOL) {
  p <- (r - d) / d
  xyr[c1, 1] <<- toroid(xyr[c1, 1] + p*dx*w1, 1)
  xyr[c1, 2] <<- toroid(xyr[c1, 2] + p*dy*w1, 2)
  xyr[c0, 1] <<- toroid(xyr[c0, 1] - p*dx*w0, 1)
  xyr[c0, 2] <<- toroid(xyr[c0, 2] - p*dy*w0, 2)

  return(TRUE)
}

  return(FALSE)
}


# ============================================================================
#  Helper function - Adjust a coordinate such that if it is distance d beyond
#  an edge (ie. outside the area) it is moved to be distance d inside the 
#  opposite edge. This has the effect of treating the area as a toroid.
# ============================================================================
toroid <- function(coord, axis) {
  tcoord <- coord

  if (coord < 0) {
    tcoord <- coord + size[axis]
  } else if (coord >= size[axis]) {
    tcoord <- coord - size[axis]
  }

  tcoord
}


# ============================================================================
#  Main program
# ============================================================================

# ------------------------------------------
# create a random initial layout
# ------------------------------------------
xyr <- matrix(0, NCIRCLES, 3)

pos0 <- 1
for (i in 1:nrow(config)) {
  pos1 <- pos0 + config[i,2] - 1
  xyr[pos0:pos1, 1] <- runif(config[i, 2], 0, size[1])
  xyr[pos0:pos1, 2] <- runif(config[i, 2], 0, size[2])
  xyr[pos0:pos1, 3] <- config[i, 1] * PRADIUS
  pos0 <- pos1 + 1
}

# ------------------------------------------
# iteratively adjust the layout
# ------------------------------------------
for (iter in 1:max.iter) {
  moved <- FALSE
  for (i in 1:(NCIRCLES-1)) {
    for (j in (i+1):NCIRCLES) {
      if (repel(xyr, i, j)) {
        moved <- TRUE
      }
    }
  }
  if (!moved) break
}

cat(paste(iter, "iterations\n"));

# ------------------------------------------
# draw the layout
# ------------------------------------------
plot(0, type="n", xlab="x", xlim=c(0,size[1]), ylab="y", ylim=c(0, size[2]))

xyr[, 3] <- xyr[, 3] / PRADIUS
for (i in 1:nrow(xyr)) {
  draw.circle(xyr[i, 1], xyr[i, 2], xyr[i, 3], "gray")
}

# ------------------------------------------
# return the layout
# ------------------------------------------
colnames(xyr) <- c("x", "y", "radius")
invisible(xyr) 
}
```

[source](http://www.r-bloggers.com/circle-packing-with-r/)